# Каким образом переданный массив изменяется внутри метода?

Tags: java, методы, static

Почему когда я передаю, например, массив какому-то статическому методу, например, `sort` из класса `Arrays`:

```
Arrays.sort(foo); //foo is array
```

Массив отсортировывается? Ведь по сути в Java массив в том самом методе станет обычным параметром и у него будет другая ссылка на обьект/примитив, ведь это метод и массив отсортируется там, в том методе. Однако чудесным образом этот массив сортируется и по ссылке `foo` я получаю отсортированный массив.

Как это работает?

Comment: "другая ссылка на обьект" - ссылка на тот же самый объект

Comment: @Igor, я это не знал! Тоесть это только со статическими методами работает?

Comment: подождите. Статичность метода здесь ни при чем. Мы же говорим об объекте, на который ссылается переменная `foo`.

Comment: Ну  вот если я создам метод где поступающее число будет умножаться на 2, к примеру. Я передам переменную `a` равную 5. После вызова метода если я выведу `a`, то увижу 5, а не 10

Comment: Массив - объект. Объект передается по ссылке. Всё.

Comment: @Flippy а-а-а, тут дело в разнице между `reference` и `value` типами

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Внутри метода `sort` происходит изменение содержимого массива и не создается новый объект.

Рассмотрим на примере похожего метода:

```
public void change(int[] bar) {
    bar[0] = 2;
}

//вызываем его
int[] foo = new int[10];//создается объект
foo[0] = 1;
change(foo);
System.out.println(foo[0]); //2
```

т.к. в методе и в вызывающем коде используется один объект, то он доступен по ссылке, изменилось только содержимое.

Магия Paint:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно и до, и после изменения переменные `foo` и `bar` обращаются к одному и тому же объекту.

Если внутри метода создать новый объект, то он извне доступен не будет:

```
public void change(int[] bar) {
    bar = new int[10];
    bar[0] = 2;
}

//вызываем его
int[] foo = new int[10];//создается объект
foo[0] = 1;
change(foo);
System.out.println(foo[0]); //1
```

После изменения, переменные ссылаются на разные объекты и поэтому изменений, выполненных с `bar` не видно через `foo`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То же самое произойдет, если передать в метод примитивный тип (`int`, `double`).

Более подробное обсуждение в английской версии: [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: С ума сойти, я это не знал, ох... Спасибо :-|

Comment: @Flippy ты не читал книгу с основами Java? О_о

Comment: Нет, я думал, что переменная поступающая в метод другая и ссылается на другой обьект, она же локальная

Comment: @Flippy но это и есть основы Java в любой обучающей книге))

Answer (score 4):

Независимо от того статичный метод или нет, в параметрах он получает копии переданных ему значений. Для примитивных типов это копии значений, а для ссылочных копии ссылок. Проще говоря, `Arrays.sort(foo)` получает ссылку на массив foo, а потому может оперировать с массивом, на который ссылается параметр.

Comment: Не понял :( простите