# вызов функции с переменной и с массивом

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] x = {0};
    int x1 = 5;
    func(x);
    func2(x1);
    System.out.print(x[0] + " ");
    System.out.print(x1);
}

public static void func(int[] a) {
    a[0] = 100;
}
public static void func2(int a) {
    a = 100;
}
```

вывод: 100 5

может кто объяснить почему массив можно менять через функцию, чем он отличается от обычной переменной

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msCqh8Mn37A&t=8s - 4:24 (4 минута, 24 секунда)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Каким образом переданный массив изменяется внутри метода?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/675820/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Answer (score 3):

Потому что в java [массив - это объект](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1):

> An object is a class instance or an array.

Детали:
1. В java есть два вида переменных: примитивные (byte, short, int, long, float, double, char, boolean) и ссылочные (классы, перечисления, интерфейсы, а также массивы). Переменные примитивного типа хранят значения своего типа, а ссылочного ссылку (значение ссылки) на экземпляр своего типа.
2. Все аргументы методов в java передаются по значению. Т.е. при вызове метода в нём неявно создаётся локальная копия, передаваемой переменной. И, если в методе изменить значение аргумента, то будет модифицирована лишь копия, не модифицируя значение исходной переменной.
3. И тут... Когда в метод передаётся переменная примитивного типа (например, int), то создаётся локальная копия этой переменной, которая и модифицируется, а, тем временем, значение оригинальной переменной остаётся неизменным. Когда же в метод передаётся переменная ссылочного типа (например, объект), то создаётся копия не самого объекта, а ссылки на объект, которая указывает на всё тот же исходный объект. Таким образом через локальную ссылку осуществляется модификация оригинального объекта или, как в данном случае, массива.

Answer (score 1):

Массив передается как указатель

Comment: Принципиальной разницы между передачей массива и переменной нет. Если сделать `a = new int[]{100};`, то изменения извне метода никто не увидит.

Answer (score 0):

Передача по ссылке или по значению.
Первая функция - это как если бы я передал функции ссылку на свой банковский счет и функция по этой ссылке может устанавливать значение на моем счету.
Вторая функция - это как если бы я сообщил функции сколько денег у меня на счету, функция поменяла это значение, но при этом на счету никаких изменений не произошло.